# How to divide datasets in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

```
firstpart = D2.loc[(D2['Age'] == "15") 
                  | (D2['Age'] == "16")
                  | (D2['City'] == "Paris")
                  | (D2['City'] == "London")
                  | (D2['City'] == "Istanbul")
                  | (D2['Health'] == "Ok")
                  ]
```

This is how I got what I wanted from the dataset but I would like to take **the rest of the dataset** and save it as a new dataset. Does pandas have some functions to do this easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my sample code. You can check it

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Age'] = ["16","17","18"]
df['City'] = ['Paris']*2 + ["London"]
df['Health'] = ['OK']*2 + ['Not Ok']

mask = (df['Age'] == "16") | (df['City'] == "Paris") | (df['Health'] == 'OK')
print(df[mask])
print(df[~mask])
```

The result is

```
  Age   City Health
0  16  Paris     OK
1  17  Paris     OK
```

and

```
  Age    City  Health
2  18  London  Not Ok
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can split your code into

```
mask = (D2['Age'] == "15") 
                  | (D2['Age'] == "16")
                  | (D2['City'] == "Paris")
                  | (D2['City'] == "London")
                  | (D2['City'] == "Istanbul")
                  | (D2['Health'] == "Ok")
fisrt_part = D2[mask]
rest_data = D2[~mask]
```

Here, I use `~` to make `False` -> `True`, and converse.

Comment: How you define "mask" here is wrong, I suppose.  Other than that, if I define the first part how I showed in the post, which works, and then do your method with ~, it gives an error

Comment: TypeError: ufunc 'invert' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: @linuxpanther, I just copied your code above, and then pasted it. Can you give me some sample data. Maybe I can give you another solution.

Comment: If you see that, I defined with "loc" and "firstpart" variable is already a dataframe, so that is done. My question is to get the rest of the dataset somehow. But ~ does not work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).